# Sharing Core Data database

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, share

I developed a Mac OSX app based on Core Data.
This database contains a lot of informations like name, phone, mail etc.
Now I would use a copy of this app on another Mac.
Is it possible that the two apps share the same database, so the two users can work 
making change to the records in database at the same time?
The two Mac are in the same local LAN.

Thanks

Comment: iCloud Core Data (quite easy)? CloudKit (more difficult)?

Comment: Try [Ensembles](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles) with Multipeer or any other cloud file system.